# Run ssh forwarding command before nagios command

Tags: linux, ssh, snmp, nagios

I have a number of machines which I would like to check using my Nagios box. They sit behind a machine which is reachable from my Nagios box; all are running Linux. These machines have no routing to outside networks. If I need to reach the machines manually I either ssh to the intermediate box and then ssh to the other machines, or I'll use ssh to forward a port.

I usually use SNMP for most of my checks. So my thought is that prior to my Nagios box running a check I could have it run a command to forward the needed port, then get rid of the forward when done. Can anyone guide me on the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into [Nagios passive checks](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/passivechecks.html).  As described in the documentation:

> Passive checks are useful for monitoring services that are:
>
> - Asynchronous in nature and cannot be monitored effectively by polling
>     their status on a regularly scheduled basis
> - Located behind a firewall and cannot be checked actively from the monitoring host

Your use case is pretty clearly the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the machines were just behind a firewall then NRDP does look like it would be a good choice. However since the machines I'm looking to monitor aren't actually able to reach the outside world except by an SSH tunnel to one machine, I'm not seeing that as ideal. Though I guess I could forward a port from each machine to the Nagios box, then send the results of the passive checks out through that.